# Get created file's path from SaveFileDialog in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, filepath, savefiledialog

I am trying to store my created file's path after using SaveFileDialog, here is my code:

```
    let path;
    dialog.showSaveDialog((fileName) => {
        if (fileName === undefined){
            console.log("You didn't save the file");
            return;
        }

        fs.writeFile(fileName, text, (err) => {
            if(err){
                alert("An error ocurred creating the file "+ err.message)
            }
            alert("The file has been succesfully saved");
        });
    });
```

What I want to happen is that after the user creates the file he would enter file's path in the variable path, is it even possible?

Comment: are you talking about extension name or absolute path of the select file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')

dialog.showSaveDialog({
    title: "Save file"
}).then((filePath_obj)=>{
    if (filePath_obj.canceled)
        console.log("canceled")
    else
        console.log('absolute path: ',filePath_obj.filePath);
});
```

Comment: I just have `dialog.showSaveDialog(...).then is not a function` ...

Answer (score 2):

you can use the sync version of `dialog.showSaveDialog`. with the sync version no need for you to declare the path variable without intializing it

```
   let path = dialog.showSaveDialog( {
        title: "Save file",
        filters: [ { name:"png pictures", ext: [ "png" ] } ], // what kind of files do you want to see when this box is opend
        defaultPath: app.getPath("document") // the default path to save file
    });

    if ( ! path ) {
        // path is undefined
        return;
    }

    fs.writeFile( path , text , ( err , buf ) => {
        if ( err )
            return alert("saved");
        return alert("not saved");
    });
```

or the async version

```
  dialog.showSaveDialog( {
        title: "Save file",
        filters: [ { name:"png pictures", ext: [ "png" ] } ], // what kind of files do you want to see when this box is opend, ( users will be able to save this kind of files )
        defaultPath: app.getPath("document") // the default path to save file
    }, ( filePath ) => {
        if ( ! filePath ) {
            // nothing was pressed
            return;
        }

        path = filePath;
        fs.writeFile( path , text , ( err , buf ) => {
            if ( err )
                return alert("saved");
            return alert("not saved");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You need to wait for the result of the dialog through the callback. Check the [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options-callback).

So something like:

```
let path; 

function saveProjectAs(text) {
    var options = {
        title: "Save project as ",
        message: "Save project as ",
        nameFieldLabel: "Project Name:",
        // defaultPath:  directory to show (optional)
    }

    dialog.showSaveDialog(mainWindow, options, saveProjectAsCallback);

    function saveProjectAsCallback(filePath) {
        // if user pressed "cancel" then `filePath` will be null
        if (filePath) {
         // check for extension; optional. upath is a node package.
            if (upath.toUnix(upath.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase() != ".json") {
                filePath = filePath + ".json"
            }

        path = filePath;

        fs.writeFile(path, text, (err) => {
           if(err){
                alert("An error ocurred creating the file "+ err.message)
            }
           alert("The file has been succesfully saved");
         });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way to get the selected file's path? isn't there a function to get that without installing other packages?

Comment: Read up on what `upath` does. . .